# What is proper way to add multiple arrows to a path in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

I checked Asymptote documentation and [this link](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/FAQ/section5.html#doublearrows), but just can manually add muptiple arrows  in the following way. However, the distances between arrow heads is not uniform, but depend on the length of the path, that is not expected.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(1,1), B=(4,3), C=(5,1);

for (real i: new real[] {.48,.5,.52}) {
draw(A--B,Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(i)));
draw(B--C,Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(i)));
draw(A--C,Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(i)));
}

dot(A^^B^^C);
label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,N);
label("$C$",C,E);
```

It's a bit strange when we can add 2 arrow heads

```
draw(A--B,
Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(.45)),
Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(.5))
); /// <<< OK!
```

but we can not add 3 arrow heads

```
draw(A--B,
Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(.45)),
Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(.5)),
Arrow(TeXHead,Relative(.55))
);    // <<< not OK
```

**Question** What is proper way to add multiple arrows to a (straight or curvy) path in Asymptote?

Answer (score 1):

I come to the following solution, and still open for better ones. My simple idea is converting `arctime` to `reltime` to use in `Arrow(Relative(i))`. It works for both straight and curvy curves. To make arrows centered at the midpoint or just touching the end of the curve, more calculations are needed.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(1,1), B=(4,3), C=(5,1);
DefaultHead=TeXHead;
// adding n arrows with distance d between arrowheads, 
// starting at point of length s from the begining of the path p
void addarrow(path p, int n=1, real s, real d=0){
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
pair M=arcpoint(p,s+i*d); // starting arrowhead
real TM=arctime(p,s+i*d); 
real LM=arclength(subpath(p,0,TM));
real tM=LM/arclength(p); // change to reltime
draw(p,Arrow(Relative(tM)));
}
}

addarrow(B--C,n=3,1,.1);
addarrow(A--B,n=4,2,.1);
path p=A.. controls A + dir(-45) and C+dir(-120) .. C;
addarrow(p,n=5,1.5,.15);

dot(A^^B^^C);
label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,N);
label("$C$",C,E);
```

With `DefaultHead=HookHead;`

[image]

```
addarrow(B--C,n=3,.8,.5);
addarrow(A--B,n=4,1.5,.4);
path p=A.. controls A + dir(-45) and C+dir(-120) .. C;
addarrow(p,n=5,1.5,.2);
```